# Django Rest Framework Generation URL in serializer for diffrent View

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm working on an API in DRF an I have come up on a problem that I don't seem to figure how to resolve.

My issue:

I have the following serializer:
`class ParameterListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Parameter
    fields = (
    'location',
    'name',
    'value',
    'created_at',
    'location'
    )
    
def get_location(self, obj):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request is None:
        return None
    return reverse('location-detail', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk}, request=request)`
```

And these URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [     path('locations/', LocationListCreateView.as_view(), name='locations'),     path('locations/<int:pk>', LocationDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='location-detail'),     path('locations/<int:pk>/parameters/', ParameterAPIView.as_view(), name='parameter-list'),     path('locations/<int:pk>/parameters/<int:parameter_pk>', ParameterAPIView.as_view(), name='parameter-details'), ]
```

I want my ParameterListSerializer to contain the location field to contain the URL to the 'location-detail' View. EX. for location 1, 'locations/1', but when I use the reverse Function I only get the value of 'pk', meaning 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

So far tried to the `reverse` function from DRF but the not getting event the URL structure, just the 'pk'

Comment: can not understand your question, can you modify this.

Comment: Sure! So when I go for example to "/locations/1/parameters/", I want to have a key named 'location' that is the URL to '/locations/1". Right now the reverse function is returning me only the 'pk' value, meaning '1', and I want the full URL to that location

Comment: Resolved! I used the reverse function as follows reverse("location-detail", kwargs={'pk': obj.location.pk} , request=request)